# Class extend with Swing not working

Tags: java, jpanel

I'm beginning with java and I'm trying to create a window with buttons (class Fenetre) and to add a picture and some text in it (class AccueilPanel) but when I build it, only the Window+buttons shows up.

It seems like the `AccueilPanel` class isn't working. Here is my code:

Class `Fenetre`:

```
package test.accueil;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class Fenetre extends JFrame{    


  public Fenetre(){

      JPanel pan = new JPanel();
        //Définition de sa couleur de fond
        pan.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);        
        //On prévient notre JFrame que notre JPanel sera son content pane
        this.setContentPane(pan);               
        this.setVisible(true);  
    this.setTitle("Box Layout");
    this.setSize(900,900);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);



    JPanel b1 = new JPanel();
    //On définit le layout en lui indiquant qu'il travaillera en ligne
    b1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(b1, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
    b1.add(new JButton("Jouer !"));
    b1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW); 


    JPanel b2 = new JPanel();
    b2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(b2, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
    b2.add(new JButton("Instructions"));
    b2.add(new JButton("Scores"));
    b2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW); 



    JPanel b4 = new JPanel();
    //On positionne maintenant ces trois lignes en colonne
    b4.setLayout(new BoxLayout(b4, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    b4.add(b1);
    b4.add(b2);
    b4.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);


    this.getContentPane().add(b4);
    this.setVisible(true);    


  }

  protected JPanel getPanel(){
        return this.b4;
    }   
    protected JPanel b4;    


    public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Fenetre fenetre = new Fenetre();

    }

}
```

Class `AccueilPanel`:

```
package test.accueil;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class AccueilPanel extends Fenetre{

    public AccueilPanel(Dimension dim){
        initPanel();
    }

    public void initPanel(){
        JLabel titre = new JLabel("Bienvenue dans le jeu du pendu\n");
        titre.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        this.b4.add(titre, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        this.b4.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/moon.jpg")), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JTextArea texte = new JTextArea("Bienvenue dans mon jeu ! ");

        texte.setEditable(false);
        texte.setBackground(Color.white);

        this.b4.add(texte, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

}
```

Could someone help me ?

Comment: Help with what? Please explain your problem and post only relevant parts. "Not working" is very vague and not understandable.

Comment: I do not see the image and the tittle. It is like the AccueilPanel class was not existing. I had the same result when I had just written the Fenetre class. I was trying to use the "extends" way for the first time.

Comment: Your AccuielPanel is not referenced in the Fenetre class - it has no way to know it even exists, let alone do anything with it!

Comment: Ok, a better way to put it would be - your main() method should be in the subclass, and creating an instance of that, not in the parent class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way subclassing is possible with your code is if the two classes' `package` are explicit. So, add say `package maison;` at the first line of both files and the runtime should be able to access both classes without problems.

Ok, I got your code to work, I'm pasting both files:

```
package test.accueil;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class AccueilPanel extends Fenetre{

    public AccueilPanel(Dimension dim){
        super();
        initPanel();
    }

    public void initPanel(){
        JLabel titre = new JLabel("Bienvenue dans le jeu du pendu\n");
        titre.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        b4.add(titre, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        b4.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/moon.jpg")), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JTextArea texte = new JTextArea("Bienvenue dans mon jeu ! ");

        texte.setEditable(false);
        texte.setBackground(Color.white);

        b4.add(texte, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

}
package test.accueil;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class Fenetre extends JFrame{    


  public Fenetre(){

      JPanel pan = new JPanel();
        //Définition de sa couleur de fond
        pan.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);        
        //On prévient notre JFrame que notre JPanel sera son content pane
        this.setContentPane(pan);               
        this.setVisible(true);  
    this.setTitle("Box Layout");
    this.setSize(900,900);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);



    JPanel b1 = new JPanel();
    //On définit le layout en lui indiquant qu'il travaillera en ligne
    b1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(b1, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
    b1.add(new JButton("Jouer !"));
    b1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW); 


    JPanel b2 = new JPanel();
    b2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(b2, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
    b2.add(new JButton("Instructions"));
    b2.add(new JButton("Scores"));
    b2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW); 



    JPanel b4 = new JPanel();
    //On positionne maintenant ces trois lignes en colonne
    b4.setLayout(new BoxLayout(b4, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    b4.add(b1);
    b4.add(b2);
    b4.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);


    this.getContentPane().add(b4);
    this.setVisible(true);    


  }

  protected JPanel getPanel(){
        return this.b4;
    }   
    protected JPanel b4;    


    public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Fenetre fenetre = new Fenetre();
    }
}
```

... and the command line I used to compile it `javac -d . Fenetre.java AccueilPanel.java`

To run it, I used `java -cp . test.accueil.AccueilPanel`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your code do you actually create an instance of your `AccueilPanel` class and set it visible. (since it is a JFrame)

You need to add the following code to the appropriate place so that one is created and shown

```
AccueilPanel accPanel = new AccueilPanel(new Dimension(100,100));
accPanel.setVisible(true);
```

However, the naming of the class suggests that you want this class to be a panel not a new frame, perhaps you should consider having it extend `JPanel` instead.